# Minimization problem associated with $\int_0^1 u'(x)v'(x)\,dx + \int_0^1 {{u(x)v(x)}\over{x^2}}\,dx = \int_0^1 {{f(x)v(x)}\over{x^2}}\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671819/does-there-exist-unique-u-in-v-satisfying-integral-equation).

> Set$$V = \{v \in H^1(0, 1) : v(0) = 0\}.$$Given $f \in L^2(0, 1)$ such that ${1\over x}f(x) \in L^2(0, 1)$, does there exist a unique $u \in V$ satisfying$$\int_0^1 u'(x)v'(x)\,dx + \int_0^1 {{u(x)v(x)}\over{x^2}}\,dx = \int_0^1 {{f(x)v(x)}\over{x^2}}\,dx \text{ for all }v \in V?\tag*{$(*)$}$$

This was answered in the affirmative. My question is, what is the minimization problem associated with $(*)$?

Comment: This was answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1679960)